# How to solve json parsing error?

Tags: android

I am working on android application.I am sending Http url to the client and get back json from them. but the received json is very large so that i can't store the json values to the String. so I am getting Enlarge buffer error

So is there any solution available to parse json value to String.I have attached My code below...

```
package ez.com;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class apiconnection {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public static URL                url; 
    public static URLConnection      urlConn; 
    public static DataInputStream    dis;
    public String str;
    public static int val;

    public static void urlconn(String url_val,Context con)
    {
        String s;
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        String jsonval=null;

        try
        {

            String urlval="http://iphone.openmetrics.com/apps/mattson/api.html"+url_val;

            System.out.println("url value for connection: " +urlval);        
            url = new URL(urlval);          
            urlConn = url.openConnection(); 
            urlConn.setDoInput(true); 
            urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
            dis = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream()); 

            if(dis.available()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(con, "No Data found Please search another option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
                ab.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=#ff0000> Network Error Please try Again" +"</font></b>"));
                ab.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
                ab.show();

            }

            while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null)
            {             

                sb.append(s);

            }           
            "**jsonval=sb.toString();**" -------------------->This line is error
            System.out.println("Json Parsed " +jsonval);
            jsonreader.json(sb.toString()); 


        }  
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Malformed URL for : "+ e);
         }
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
              throw new IllegalStateException("IO Exception for  : " + e);
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: More information is needed?, from which url do you get the json string? How do you pass,? what error do you get? will you update the question adding these details??

Comment: open the very same url with a browser. **How big is it?** I've downloaded many long files without incurring in this problem. Are you sure you want to download such a big file on a mobile device? Can't you get something smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to split up the JSON data into parseable parts that are small enough to fit into the buffer?

Comment: For example, you could check if the line you are reading contains the end of a suitable JSON structure. If it does, and you've read a lot of JSON already, substring it and parse the JSON part. Then continue with the next part. Using this technique, you are creating a buffer for the JSON parser to prevent too much data to be parsed at the same time.